# How to convert Javascript code to Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me, here is the code in Javascript, I need to change this code to Jquery.

```
eval("parent.document.forms[0].strKey" + 
      intDimensionId).value = strIds[intDimensionId];
```

Comment: How the HTML looks like? What are you trying to do? Please give more info so we can **realy** help you. Anway, it's bad javascript code anyway, You should never use `eval` it's evil and the need of using it point you have bad code design.

Answer (score 1):

high performance:
minimal jQuery: `$('form:first')[0]["strKey" + intDimensionId].value = strIds[intDimensionId];`

not as high performance:
full jQuery: `$('form:first *[name="strKey' + intDimensionId + '"]').val(strIds[intDimensionId]);`

Comment: without jQuery at all (w/ a little help from Krister): `parent.document.forms[0]["strKey" + intDimensionId].value = strIds[intDimensionId];`

Answer (score 0):

This should work although there are really plenty of ways to do this. Also note the use of the input tag. Your code may use a different tag so update accordingly.

```
$('input[name=strKey'+intDimensionId+']',
   parent.document.forms[0]).val(strIds[intDimensionId]);
```

Comment: yes, but the proper statement would be: `'input[name=strKey'+intDimensionId+'],select[name=strKey'+intDimensionId+']'`...regardless jQuery is not required at all for this (see the comment on my post)