# How to change javascript code to Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Javascript code to Jquery code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828381/how-to-convert-javascript-code-to-jquery-code)

I need to convert this javascript code to Jquery?

`eval("document.forms[0].strKey" + intDimId).value + "," + tarr[i];`

Can you please  help me how to change the above code to jQuery

Thanks,

Rajasekhar.

Comment: Eval is Evil. Use it only when you dont have any option

Answer (score 2):

One word: ***DON'T***.

If you have working JavaScript, "converting" it to jQuery is a DOWNGRADE.

But you really should learn about arrays. Seriously, just rewrite your code as:

```
document.forms[0]['strKey'+intDimId].value + "," + tarr[i];
```

Comment: How is using jQuery instead of plain JS a downgrade?

Comment: @lanzz jQuery is ultimately "converted" to javascript. Hence, it's a downgrade. jQuery is used mainly 'coz it saves you a lot of time.

Comment: @lanzz jQuery is a higher "language" than JavaScript. JavaScript is already a high-level, interpreted language. Adding yet another layer is just daft, in my opinion.

Comment: So you don't believe there are any benefits in using libraries in any language? And you find an inherent benefit in directly supporting quirks and bugs in a large bunch of incompatible browsers?

Comment: @lanzz my comment was in response to this answer, that changing one line of code from javascript to jQuery is a downgrade, which I believe it is.